# while loop for when the database has values submitted to post to div

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I am trying to execute a while loop for when the database has values submitted for actual_quote and poster, and when it has those values it posts the div where those values are displayed, and for each row a new div is placed for that single row.
I am not sure where to go about this, any help?

```
 <div class="wrapper">
<?php $db_name = 'submissions';
$db_user = 'root';
 $db_pass = '';
 $db_host = 'localhost';
 mysql_connect("localhost", $db_user, $db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("submissions") or die(mysql_error());
```

I tried starting here for while loop

```
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($actual_quote, $poster))
{
echo"
<div class="submissions">
    <div class="logo-logo"><h2>Questions.</h2>
<div class="checkboxes"><?= !empty($_GET['x']) ? $_GET['x'] : '' ?>
 </div>

    </div>
  <?php
 $actual_quote = mysql_query("SELECT actual_quote FROM data");
 $info = mysql_fetch_array( $actual_quote ); 
?>
<div class="top-submit">
<?php echo '&#8220;' . $info['actual_quote'] . '&#8221;'; ?>
</div>
<?php
$poster = mysql_query("SELECT poster FROM data");
$info = mysql_fetch_array( $poster ); 
?>
<div class="poster"><?php echo '-' . $info['poster']; ?>
<div class = "like">
 <a href = "javascript:countClicksLike();" class = "btn btn-large" style =   "color:green;">Like</a>
<p id = "like" style = "color:green;">0</p>
</div>
<div class = "dislike">
<a href = "javascript:countClicks();" class = "btn btn-large" style = "float:right;   color:red;">Dislike</a>
<p id = "dis" style = "color:red;">0</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- use select to get the items to stay on the page-->

</div>
</div>"

}
?>
```

but I am completely lost. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you better start using PHP's `PDO` rather than the `mysql` extensions, it'll save you a lot of trouble, and syntax and error handling are somewhat cleaner:

Example:

```
$DBH = new PDO('mysql:host=http://yourhost.com;dbname=yourdbname;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$STH = $DBH->prepare('SELECT * FROM `yourtable` WHERE `yourcolumn` = ?');
$STH->bindParam(1, $yourparam);
$STH->execute();

$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$mydata = array();
while ($var = $STH->fetch()) {
    /* Retrieve the information */
    $mydata[] = $var;
}

$DBH = null;
```

You can use `prepared statements` which automatically escape all invalid or problematic characters. You can also make a prepared statement and reuse it to insert large series of data while it optimizes the whole process:

```
$DBH = new PDO('mysql:host=http://yourhost.com;dbname=yourdbname;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$STH = $DBH->prepare('INSERT INTO `yourtable` (`column1`, `column2`) VALUES (?, ?)');

foreach($array as $value) {
    $STH->bindParam(1, $value);
    $STH->bindParam(2, $value);
    $STH->execute();
}

$DBH = null;
```

You can find more information on [**phpro.org's PDO tutorial pages**](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html). They are pretty well explained.

**And regarding your question (an example using PDO)**:

```
<?php
    $DBH = new PDO('mysql:host=http://yourhost.com;dbname=yourdbname;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
    $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $STH = $DBH->prepare('SELECT * FROM `yourtable` WHERE `yourcolumn` = ?');
    $STH->bindParam(1, $yourparam);
    $STH->execute();

    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    /* Store your data here */
    $mydata = array();
    while ($var = $STH->fetch()) {
        $mydata[] = $var;
    }

    $DBH = null;
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <!-- TODO html header stuff -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        /* And use it here */
        foreach($mydata as $data) {
            echo
                '<div>
                    <span>'.$data->column1.'</span>
                    <span>'.$data->column2.'</span>
                    <span>'.$data->column3.'</span>
                </div>';
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I suggest you separate the part where your script gathers data and the part where it displays it, i.e. queries go **before** the header (and even the `html` element). And then you can open `<?php … ?>` tags whenever you want to use data previously retrieved.